# Running website from home server. Can only access the website from home network, but ssh from anywhere

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, website

I've been told to try and "port forward" but I'm having a hard time getting that to work. My Belkin router supports virtual servers. I have it configured so that inbound port 8080 goes to private port 80. So now, how do I access my domain on port 8080? Do I configure my A record to point to port 8080 of my ip? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Does it work if you specify your external ip directly? like http://YOURIP:8080?

Comment: It does not, even on my home network which my server is on. Pinging also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your web browser, specify the port in the address:

> http://www.mydomain.com:8080/

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Chrome reports a "could not connect" error. When I try to ping it I get an "Unknown host" error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you spoken with your ISP's support staff?  Many ISPs block incoming http traffic because they don't want home customers running web servers from their networks.  Some of them which do block will allow you to host for no additional cost if you sign an agreement about what you host, some will only allow if you upgrade to a business class account and some won't allow anything at all.

Comment: I will try to contact them. Isn't the port forwarding masking it as http traffic? I'm not really trying to get around it, I'm just trying to understand how it all works.

Comment: No, its not the port that identifies something as http traffic.  It's the underlying transport mechanism that carries the data to that specified port.  The only significance of ports 80 and 443 are that they are specified as the defaults for http and https traffic.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated above alot of ISPs block port 80, so you have indicated you are using port 8080 instead to get around that. If you open up a terminal and do an ifconfig eth0, which I assume is the interface you are using you are getting some kind of private address such as 192.168.0.x blah blah if not a 10.x.x.x or 172.x.x.x for an IPv4 address, I just want to make sure that on your router for the port-forwarding you are doing an incoming port 8080 - and routing that to your internal web server port 80 with private address of 192.168.x.x whatever is being shown on that ifconfig screen? 
It's possible your router is also setup to block pings on the WAN interface so a ping may not respond.

Also you say SSH works, is the SSH access to your router or your Linux box?

Comment: The SSH is to my linux box, I can SSH in using either my external IP address or my domain name. And yes, when I do an ifconfig eth0 I get 192.168.2.3. Here are some images of my router settings so you can tell me if I'm being crazy. [link](http://imgur.com/a/EFZbz)

Comment: I just disable the WAN ping block, so now I can ping my linux box using both my domain or my external ip address.

Comment: Hi Devin, so something that is throwing me off is that you access your Belkin router's web interface through port 8080 i.e. localhost:8080, so maybe try changing the the port forward to 8081 to port 80 on your web server and then try to access your website externally with port 8081? Nice screenshots though very helpful. Also maybe disable DMZ, when I do port forwarding I don't also put the machine on the DMZ. I thought the DMZ was to completely expose a machine on the internet and put it outside of the Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

What your experiencing may be normal. A few [Residential Gateway Routers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residential_gateway) fail to resolve  [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS) to [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP) for local site resolution. My own being one of them.

- Setup your server.
- Configure your firewall.
- [Forward your port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forward) at the router.
- Make sure your domain service has current ip ex: [dyndns.org](http://dyn.com/dns/)
- Use a [proxy service](http://www.webproxy.ca/) to verify it's running outside your network.
- Use [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) for local name resolving.
- If you have local [DNS Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Server) define your [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) there in lue of using [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file).